# How to store special characters (', ", &, etc) in mysql database, so they can be searchable?

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a small problem with storage of special characters like quotes, double quotes and ampersands. I put every POST request through mysql_real_escape_string(), and when I add a string like `"That '70s Show"` it gets stored as `"That &#x27;70s Show"` in the mysql DB. When I echo it out, it works fine... but when I try to run a % $string % search for `"That '70s Show"`, it will not find the record. I have magic_quotes disabled.

How can I get around this?

Comment: are you mysql\_real\_escape_string()'ing your %$string% search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're not just running the incoming data that you store in the database through `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but also `htmlentities()` or a relative.  Is that the case?  If so, quit. :)

Comment: +1: Something more is definiteiy going on, as mysql_real_escape_string will change ' to '' or \' (I haven't checked which).

Comment: Another possibility is an encoding mismatch, but I'm holding out hope for the easy option.

Comment: Im not. Its just mysql_real_escape_string and thats it.

Comment: Ahhh, I cant believe I didnt notice this before. This is happeing with a scrapper script that scrapes data from IMDB, which encodes special characters and echos them out as encoded strings. Is there a function that will take &#x27; and &#x26; and decode them back to ' and & ?

Answer (score 1):

***Quoted from Mysql reference doc***

There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:

- A “'” inside a string quoted with “'”  may be written as “''”.
- A “"” inside a string quoted with “"”  may be written as “""”.
- Precede the quote character by an escape character (“\”).
- A “'” inside a string quoted with “"” needs no special treatment and need
  not be doubled or escaped. In the same way, “"” inside a string quoted
  with “'” needs no special treatment.

The following SELECT statements demonstrate how quoting and escaping work:

```
mysql> SELECT 'hello', '"hello"', '""hello""', 'hel''lo', '\'hello';
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
| hello | "hello" | ""hello"" | hel'lo | 'hello |
+-------+---------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

Refer : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html